# Get NullPointerException when using callback to set textview text in parent fragment's view

Tags: android, callback, nullpointerexception, fragment

I am getting an error that I have not been able to figure out after weeks of trying.

I am trying to do an example of a fragment that opens another dialog fragment when i click a button.

The dialog fragment has an edittext view that i am trying to use to enter a name and then when i click ok the fragment is suppose to use an interface to complete a callback to the calling fragment and then to take the text from the edittext and use it to update the text in a textview in the first fragment's layout, but no matter what i do it will not work.

I have run out of ideas of what is wrong and how to fix it.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
the compiler says line 72 gives the error in DialogFragment (NullPointerException)
(I put a // line 72 comment on that line) 
mListener.setsNewUsername(etEnteredName.getText().toString());// line 72
```

**main activity**

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentsActivity extends Activity
implements SignInDialogFragment.MyDialogListener{

String sNewUsername = new String("[Enter Username]");



public void setsNewUsername(String sNewUsername) {
    this.sNewUsername = sNewUsername;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

    TextView textViewFrag1 =(TextView)dialog.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewFragment1);
    textViewFrag1.setText("Hello" + sNewUsername);
}

@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {


}
```

}

---

**main fragment**

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState){

    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onCreateView");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
}

public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onAttach");
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onCreate");

}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onActivityCreated");
}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    Button btnShowSignin =   (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnShowSignInDialog);
    btnShowSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SignInDialogFragment signinDialog = new    SignInDialogFragment();
            signinDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);

        }

    });
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onStart");
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onResume");


}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onPause");
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onStop");

}

public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onDestroyView");
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onDestroy");
}

public void onDetach(){
    super.onDetach();
    Log.d("Fragment 1", "onDetach");
}
```

}

---

**dialog fragment**

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SignInDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

View dialogView;
EditText etEnteredName;

String enteredUserName = new String("My Name");

public String getEnteredUserName() {
    return enteredUserName;
}

public void setEnteredUserName(String enteredUserName) {
    this.enteredUserName = enteredUserName;
}

public interface MyDialogListener {
    public void setsNewUsername(String string);
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

MyDialogListener mListener;

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (MyDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.signin, null))

           .setPositiveButton("SignIn", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   etEnteredName = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.username);

                   mListener.setsNewUsername(etEnteredName.getText().toString());      // line 72

                   mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(SignInDialogFragment.this);

               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               }

           });      
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void dismiss() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

}


}
```

---

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<fragment 
    android:name="com.example.fragments.Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#00FF00">


<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textViewFragment1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SignIn Dialog Text Here"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnShowSignInDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show SignIn Dialog"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**signin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Explain with error log window

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
 etEnteredName = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.username);
```

to

```
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signin,null); 
 etEnteredName = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
```

You need to use the inflated view object to initialize your `EditText`. EditText is in `R.layout.signin`. `findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout.

Declare `View v;` as a instance variable.

Then

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signin,null);
builder.setView(v);
```

Then

```
etEnteredName = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your first suggestion and it fixed the null pointer error, but now when it goes back into the callback method in the main activity class it drops the entered name and just updates the text to read "Hello".  I'll try the second suggestion you mentioned also.  By the way, did you mean that in place of the first method?  They seem to address the same thing, just wasn't sure.  Thanks for the help.  I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: @user3064141 both are same i explained it in a better way second time. and what is the expected result? what do you want?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  The expected result is that the name entered in the dialog fragment editText will be sent back to the Activity class through the callback methods defined in the interface and then once back in the method in the activity it will use it to update the textview in the fragment1.xml layout to say Hello [name].

Comment: @user3064141 your edittext is intialized and then you get the text form it. so get the editext value on button click. first try setting a dummy value like hello testing and see if it works

Comment: @user3064141 where is your textview in which xml?? you can put a log statement in `setsNewUsername` and check the string value.

Comment: Hi.  Good news.  It seems to be working now.  I don't know exactly what fixed it.  I tried a few more things.  I did your test and found that the toast in onClick in dialog fragment was empty and then I tried a few things and now it works.  Not sure which change did it.  Here is the different code that works.  I have pasted both the onClick in the dialog fragment and the onDialogPositiveClick method in the activity so you can see what I changed in case you are curious and think you might see what did it.  Thanks a lot for the help.  I have been stuck on this forever.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3064141 i have done this many times. so i know it will work.

Comment: sorry can't add most recent code.  no room.  thanks for the help.  it works now.  I'll study it to learn what changes fixed it.  Thanks.